# Finding height balanced BST from sorted array

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, depth

I am having trouble understanding why my code is incorrect. A height balanced bst is defined as a binary tree in which the depth of the two subtrees of every node never differ by more than 1

For the given sorted array, [0,1,2,3,4,5] I got [3,2,5,1,null,4,null,0] but this answer was incorrect, I do not understand why since the maximum depth difference here is 1 ?

Correct solution is [3,1,5,0,2,4]

```
def sortedArrayToBST(self, nums: List[int]) -> TreeNode:

    if not nums:
        return None

    mid = len(nums)//2

    root = TreeNode(nums[mid])
    root.left = self.build_tree(root.left, nums, 0, mid-1)
    root.right = self.build_tree(root.right, nums, mid+1, len(nums)-1)

    return root

def build_tree(self, node, nums, lo, hi):

    if hi < lo:
        return node

    node = TreeNode(nums[hi])
    hi -= 1
    node.left = self.build_tree(node.left, nums, lo, hi)
    return node
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand either how you "get" `[3,2,5,1,null,4,null,0]` from this code, nor how that represents a tree.

Comment: Anyway, by what standard was the answer deemed "incorrect", and what is supposedly the "correct" answer?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  Its array representation of BST, read from L-R

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am not sure why it was incorrect myself thats why I made this post, I added the correct solution to main post

Comment: First off, the tree could have multiple internal structures for a given left-to-right order of leaf nodes, so that doesn't tell me enough. Second, how did you verify that you actually get the tree you think you do? I don't see how your code builds the tree properly. In particular, in the recursive step, how do you build subtrees on the right-hand side of the current node? And why aren't the children of `self` modified?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The ordering of the tree I just infered from question here, https://leetcode.com/problems/convert-sorted-array-to-binary-search-tree/ , submitting my solution gave me the output I expectd but it was deemed incorrect. The RHS sub tree is just  all nodes being added to the left subtrees.